# Rails user model with multiple roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I'm new to rails and I want to understand how to properly define an User model and its roles/types. In the app that I am writing I have 3 types of users: Client, Staff, Admin with the following functionality constraints

- All 3 user types can have access to different functionality of the application
- A Staff can be also be a Client.
- An Admin can also be a Staff or can be a Client or both. An Admin can be a Client **without being a Staff**.
- Staff, Admin will have access to the application (username/password). Client may or may not have access to the application.

The application also has a Service (the definition of the service: name, price, etc) and a ServiceInstance (the sold service) model.

- The ServiceInstance is "provided" to a user who is a Client (Staff
  and Admin can be Clients also)
- The ServiceInstance is "performed" by a "Staff" (Admin can be a Staff
  also).

Any suggestion/feedback is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like Staff, Admin & Clients will be key concepts for your application.  I would create a model for each of these, and have a one to one (has_one or belongs_to) relationship with User.  Then you could add validations on User to allow/disallow the combinations of staff, admin & client.

ADDITION: This means that user is still the model that represents someone that can log into your system.  If this user is a client and staff then it has these two models associated.

ServiceInstance has an association to Client called 'provided_by'.  ServiceInstance has an association to Staff called 'performed_by'.  Of course Client and Staff actually indicate a user, but a user in a specific context/role.

If ever you need to show a list of clients, staff or admins, you simply query that table, but print the associated user information.  If you need to show a list of all users, query the users table and show an icon or something for whether they are a client, staff, admin or combination of them.

ADDITION: Thus your comment of a user that is staff and a client, will be in the staff and client table since that user has both roles.

Comment: Let's say I have 3 models as suggested. How would I display the list of Clients to include the Staff entities which are also Clients? Also,  a Staff entity may not be a Client at the creation. It can become also a Client entity when it is actually a Client of the ServiceInstance entity.